# Can't get from web api with complex parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I have this function in my web api backend

```
[HttpGet]
public WmsWebStatus<OrdemRecebimento> CriaOrdemRecebimento(OrdemRecebimento ordemRecebimentoContrato)
{
  try
  {
    WmsWebStatus<OrdemRecebimento> retorno = WmsWebStatus<OrdemRecebimento>.Autenticacao.WMS1001;
    retorno.Retorno = Resolve<IOrdemRecebimentoServico>().CriaOrdemRecebimento(ordemRecebimentoContrato);
    return retorno;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    WriteLog.Exception(ex);
    return WebserviceUtil.ObterStatus<OrdemRecebimento>(ex);
  }
}
```

and I have this on my angular factory

```
app.factory('recebimentoServico', function ($q, $resource, $http) {  servico.teste = function (parametros) {
return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
  $resource(urlWebService + '/Recebimento/', null)
    .get({teste: "produto"}, function (dados) {
      resolve(dados);
    }, function (erro) {
      reject(erro);
    });
}); }  return servico;});
```

where I have {teste: "produto"}, I want to pass a JSON object that matches the OrdemRecebimento object

but it seems that whenever I try to pass a JSON object, it always come as null in the backend.

How can I pass an JSON object to my Web API backend?

Comment: Does this method create an order (based on my google translate of the name)? If so do not use Http Get, use Post instead as you are modifying data and that is what Post is for. Once you fix that then use `$http.post` to send the data to your web api. I see no call in your current angular code, $resource is not the same as $http.

Comment: Who put this question as `off-topic`, this IS a programming question....

Comment: @Igor is correct, use `$http` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thank you Igor, I'll try to use POST

Comment: it worked, post an answer so I can accept it please. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this method create an order (based on my google translate of the name)? If so do not use Get (`[HttpGet]`), use Post (`[HttpPost]`) instead as you are modifying data and that is what Post is for.

Once you fix that then use $http.post to send the data to your web api.